# MySQL limit function use

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I have a function stored in MySQL which accesses sensitive information via a user's UUID... Is it possible to lock down a function in MySQL so that it can only return for a single record within a query? The idea is to prevent the data from being returned via a `SELECT SENSITIVE_FUNCTION(UUID) FROM users;` sort of scenario should the front end server for any reason become compromised.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1
```

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15 To retrieve all
>   rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can
>   use some large number for the second parameter. This statement
>   retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615; With one argument,
>   the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of
>   the result set:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5;     # Retrieve first 5 rows In other words,
>   LIMIT row_count is equivalent to LIMIT 0, row_count.

Comment: The question isn't how can I limit the number of records returned, but rather it is possible to prevent a function from returning a value from multiple records within the same query. The idea is to make it so that it is only possible to return the data for a single record at a time.

Comment: Isn't that what LIMIT essentially does?

Comment: Not in the scenario I'm referring to. LIMIT sets a restriction on the number of records returned by a query, I'm trying to limit the number of times a function can be called by a query. If the frontend of this application is compromised I'm going to functionally assume they have access to craft their own queries using the credentials supplied by the web application. This function runs under a different credentials to access data on a much more restricted separate database and can be called by the web app credentials.